# How to make French vowel ɛ̃ in HTML?

Tags: html, unicode

I want to embed `ɛ̃` into my HTML page.

This is my code at present but it does not work correctly.

```html
 <p>s&#603tilde&#720k</p>
```

Comment: I am French, and I have never used this vowel. É, È, Ë and Ê are French, but not this one.
Maybe in phonetic language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.For future references for other unicode see https://mothereff.in/html-entities .

```html
&#x25B;&#x303;
```

Comment: thank you very much please could you tell me why I cannot give more than 1 in terms of grading scale?

Answer (score 1):

`ɛ̃` is a combination of two Unicode characters: "latin small letter open e" (U+025B) and a "combining tilde" (U+0303)

In HTML it can be expressed as:

```
&#x25B;&#x303;
```

*(leading 0s removed)*